# missing line number issue in fabric crashlytics log

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

We are using the fabric crashlytics to track crash report. While application crash, we can see the crash log in fabric console. In that crash log we can see the "missing" text for framework class files.

Is there any way to resolve this "missing" text in the crash log for framework class file?

[Sample crashlytics log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biiwN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashlytics needs the framework dSYM to symbolicate the stack traces and show line numbers.

If this is a publicly distributed framework and you don't have the dSYM to upload, Crashlytics can't show line numbers.

If this is an internal framework and you have the dSYM, you can configure the upload-symbols script to upload all of your dSYMs at build time: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script

Comment: Thanks Alexizamerican. After I manually uploaded the dSYM file for private framework, I can able to see the framework crash code lines.

Comment: That's great to hear!